# How to create pre-publish and post-publish scripts in VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to create a script that does some actions, then publish the site to the production, and then runs another script within Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it's possible. I thing that you need [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28VS.90%29.aspx). It already have a [lot default tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z253716%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) like copying, deleting, etc. Also there are a lot third party tasks for MSBuild like [SDCTasks](http://sdctasks.codeplex.com/) or [Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/)

For example here the one of various ways to deploy web site (using SDCTasks).  In this example both web site solution and web services solution will be builded and in case of success they will be published to some remote server and properly configured with release version configuration files.

```
   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\SDCTasks\Microsoft.Sdc.CommonWOBizTalk.tasks"/>
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../website.sln">
            <Targets></Targets>
            <Properties></Properties>
        </SolutionToBuild>

        <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../../services.sln">
            <Targets></Targets>
            <Properties></Properties>
        </SolutionToBuild>

    </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishFolder>\\myservername\deployto</PublishFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AfterCompile" DependsOnTargets="PublishWebSite;PublishServices;SetConfiguration"/>

  <Target Name="PublishWebSite">
    <Folder.CleanFolder Path="$(PublishFolder)" Force="True" />
    <Folder.CopyFolder Source="$(OutDir)_PublishedWebsites\MyWebSite" Destination="$(PublishFolder)" />
  </Target> 

  <Target Name="PublishServices">
    <MakeDir Directories="$(PublishFolder)\Services"/>
    <Folder.CopyFolder Source="$(OutDir)_PublishedWebsites\MyService" Destination= "$(PublishFolder)\ Services" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="SetConfiguration">
      <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutDir)_PublishedWebsites\MyWebSite\WebRelease.config" DestinationFiles="$(PublishFolder)\web.config" />
      <Copy SourceFiles="$(OutDir)_PublishedWebsites\MyService\WebRelease.config" DestinationFiles="$(PublishFolder)\Services\web.config" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Possible, maybe, but Micorsoft have made is so awkward that I'm not going to bother.
I'll just write a batch file to copy the files I need rather than messing around all afternoon with stupid xml.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what your looking for would be a [macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967.aspx) that would perform the actions before calling publish, then perform some additional actions. If you're using TFS 2010 as well then you could customize a build definition to do what you're looking for as well.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer covering the "pre-publish" part (tested within VS2017, but I think this should work in previous versions as well):

1. Open Web publishing configuration file (e.g. Test.pubxml)
2. Define a target that executes a custom scripts located somewhere within your project (e.g. some Powershell script within an inner folder). This code should be put within the `Project` tag, after the first `PropertyGroup`:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <PipelineDependsOn>
       ExtBuild;
       $(PipelineDependsOn);
     </PipelineDependsOn>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <Target Name="ExtBuild">
     <Message Text="Building something else" Importance="high"/>
     <Exec Command="powershell.exe -file &quot;$(ProjectDir)\Publish\publish.ps1&quot;" />
   </Target>
   ```

**Note:** the current directory is `$(ProjectDir)`, so be careful when including other ps1 files from the target one

Comment: This work for pre-publish. Can you please mention the changes needed to make this work as post-publish?

Comment: for completeness: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#run-a-target-before-or-after-publishing

Answer (score -1):

For pre-publish, at least for ClickOnce, you may add:

```
<Target Name="ClearPrevPulish" BeforeTargets="PublishOnly">
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishUrl)" />
</Target>
```